# How to open credits url of highcharts in new tab

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I make the highcharts credits `url` to open in new tab?

```
credits: {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'text',
    href: 'url'
},
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could redefine the credits click handler after the plot is drawn in the charts load event:

```
    chart: {
        events:{
            load: function() {
                this.credits.element.onclick = function() {
                    window.open(
                      'http://www.example.com',
                      '_blank'
                    );
                 }
            }
        }                
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G9h8z/1/).

Comment: This unfortunately cannot be stringified with JSON.

Answer (score 6):

Here is solution that worked for me.

```
credits: {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'text',
    href: 'javascript:window.open("http://www.example.com/", "_blank")'
},
```

Answer (score 3):

**http://jsfiddle.net/ptasdfmk/**

```
// Plugin to add support for credits.target in Highcharts.
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'showCredits', function (proceed, credits) {
    proceed.call(this, credits);

    if (credits.enabled && this.credits) {
        this.credits.element.onclick = function () {

            // dynamically create an anchor element and click it
            // use the settings defined in highcharts (credits.target)

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = credits.href;
            link.target = credits.target;
            link.click();

        }
    }
});

$('#container').highcharts({

    credits: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'CREDITS',
        href: 'http://example.com',
        target: '_blank'
    },  

});
```

Using the Highcharts configuration (credits section with target) a new link element is created on the fly and clicked, when you click "CREDITS". Chained events. This allows to reuse the code and act based on the configuration.

Comment: this "plugin" will change all a tags href and target attributes

Comment: thanks. i used the `$('a')` selector wrongly - basically, i wanted to express how to "create a link on the fly and trigger it". Updated my answer with a fix.